# Apple developer: Problema al pagar la licencia

Tags: ios, macos, iphone

tengo un problema a la hora de intentar pagar la licencia del apple developer, lo he intentado con varias tarjetas de credito y debito asi como con paypal pero me sigue lanzando el mismo error, algún consejo que pueda servir en este caso?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me brinden

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dudo que nosotros podamos ayudarte, ya que es un sitio sobre problemas de programacion.. le preguntaste a ellos o a tus tarjetas???